# Git conflict seen between two branches that are in-sync

Tags: git, gitlab

**Preamble/context:**

Sorry for the lack of hard evidence here, just trying to gather conceptual info on a particular git issue I ran into, and see if anyone else has encountered anything similar.

I'm not new to git, and several minutes of googling my problem only yields answers to the general issue of resolving git conflicts, which isn't my issue.

In case it's relevant, I'm using gitlab 14.0 to manage my remote git repos: https://about.gitlab.com/releases/categories/releases/

**Issue**

The issue I encountered was in trying to merge a "development branch" into the "master branch" of a particular project, through the Gitlab UI (so, the merge process is dealing with remote versions of the development and master branches). Gitlab told me there were conflicts so I couldn't merge, however, it couldn't show me what files were impacted by the conflicts. Gitlab also told me the development branch was in-sync with master branch (i.e. there are no commits on master that are not incorporated to the development branch). This is a contradiction in itself. If the development branch already has all the commits applied to master, how can it be in conflict with master?

In my local version of the development branch, I did not see the alleged conflict. Pulling and pushing to the remote development branch (to ensure it was in sync, which it was), and then pulling in the remote master branch yielded no changes and the message "Already up to date." So no conflict was seen locally between the two branches. It was only gitlab that was reporting a conflict, which again, didn't make sense even just looking at the remote branches.

Has anyone else encountered such a thing, and what am I supposed to make of it? I usually view git in a glowing light, to the point that I can be almost certain any errors are my own fault and not git's. But this one does seem to be git's fault.

Comment: Maybe GitLab UI's fault, but I would not suspect Git itself...

Comment: Try fetching, then checking one of the *remote* branches and then merging the other *remote* branch..... I'm not saying this is solving your sync between local/remote branches.... it's just so that you can see what gitlab is workikg with.

Comment: Committing and pushing a dummy-edit on the development branch seems to have convinced gitlab that there isn't a conflict, allowing the merge. However, and this is what really confuses me, comparing the hashes of pre-dummy-edit and post-dummy-edit shows a whole bunch of changes. So something is out of sorts somewhere

Comment: This statement might explain why you didn't see the conflict: "In my local version of the development branch, I did not see the alleged conflict. Pulling and pushing to the remote development branch (to ensure it was in sync, which it was)...". Maybe your local `development` had the conflict resolution already and you pushed it out. Had you compared the remote branches instead of your local branches I assume you would have seen the conflicts.

Comment: Also, Regarding: "Gitlab also told me the development branch was in-sync with master branch (i.e. there are no commits on master that are not incorporated to the development branch)" *How* did Gitlab tell you that?

Comment: Side note- is it possible the MR you were looking at just needed to be refreshed? Is there a refresh button or is it always automatic if either the source or target branch changes?